# Resources for learning vocal signal processing

Tags: voice

I was wondering if anyone could point me to any good resources on learning vocal signal processing. I have already learned a chunk of general DSP, but I haven't found any good resources for vocal signal processing in particular.
By vocal signal processing I mean things like voice transformation and voice conversion, and things like source modifications which may be audio signal processing and not just vocal signal processing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what specifically? Voice compression (Vocoders)? Speaker identification? Speech-to-text? Voice enhancement for phones? Tuning mechanism for singing? Speaker localization and isolation (e.g. for conference table speakers)? Text-to-speech? Voice removal (for Karaoke, for example)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller By vocal signal processing I mean things like voice transformation and voice conversion, and things like source modifications which may be audio signal processing and not just vocal signal processing. I have changed my question to add this clarification. Thanks!

Comment: What'sa *"voice transformation"*?  What about the voice is getting transformed?  And what about the voice is getting converted?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is something like "vocal signal processing", but there is such thing as 'audio signal processing'.

If you are interested in the coding part, there is a really nice library called NAudio, written in the .NET framework. Here: https://github.com/naudio

You can process audio input using this library, which in your case is voice, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous answer already stated, it may be best to start with generic audio/music signal processing.

There are many interesting books on the topic, I would maybe recommend Udo Zoelzners "DAFX" as a starting point, or Christensens's "Introduction to Audio Processing".

It may also be worth checking out a book on Speech Processing to learn about the process of how speech is processed in general.